# Problem with checking if div is empty works only in the begining

Tags: jquery

I met a problem while trying to check if `p` in `div` is empty. These spans are being removed by users clicking on them and I want to alert something when they all dissapear. I tried this Jquery script below but it only works in the begining when I load page.

```
html
<div class="skladniki">
<p>
<span> example </span>
<span> example </span>
<span> example </span>
<span> example </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

              if ($('.skladniki').is(':empty')){
  console.log("elo");
}
       });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message should be displayed when the removal is happening. Here is an example, and I just check for the length of spans instead of checking to see if the paragraph is empty.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".skladniki span").on("click", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    if($(".skladniki span").length == 0){
       console.log("empty!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skladniki">
  <p>
    <span> example </span>
    <span> example </span>
    <span> example </span>
    <span> example </span>
  </p>
</div>
```